# where does AD get logon datestamp

Tags: powershell, cmd, active-directory

I'm running a basic Powershell script to get and AD users last logon date and in the case of this user (myself, after logging in this morning, 7/21/2014) results in: 7/9/2014 7:33:35 AM

```
get-aduser -Filter 'samaccountname -eq "my.account"' -properties * | select-object name, lastlogondate
```

However, when I run net user from CMD, I get: Last logon 7/17/2014 11:23:14 AM

```
net user %(ask:User Name:my.account) /domain
```

Any idea why the discrepancies?  And why it's not reporting today's date/time?

WIN 2008 R2 Domain and Forest.

A few observations, looking at ADUC GUI > Attribute Editor, I notice that lastLogon is 7/17/2014, lastLogonTimestamp is 7/21/2014 and whenChanged is the same as lastLogonTimestamp.

Comment: This isnt really a programming question. Read this post and it should help explain why there is a difference: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/1ae08081-dcfe-44cd-bc3b-f5ac26d53f76/difference-between-lastlogon-and-lastlogontimestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LastLogon is not replicated.  The LastLogon property on any given DC for any given account records the last time that account logged on to that DC.  To get the last domain logon for the account, you have to retrieve the LastLogon from all the DCs, and take the newest one.